# Double tap/click ruining JS memory game

Tags: javascript, double-click

When user-testing a memory game with my 4-year-old, she discovered a bug. When you double-tap on a card it considers it a match. I tried to disable the that had been clicked using `this.style.pointerEvents = 'none'`  then setting it back to auto.

This works for the second clicked card but not the first (defeating the point of using it and creating a new bug! The project is currently deployed at: https://dandavies23.github.io/smoothie-moves/

If you’ve any ideas on how I could do this better greatly appreciated!

````
      function tumblerLift() {
        let cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id')
        this.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        cardsChosen.push(fruitVegArray[cardId].name)
        cardsChosenId.push(cardId)
        this.setAttribute('src', fruitVegArray[cardId].img)
        console.log(fruitVegArray[cardId])
        if (cardsChosen.length === 2) {
            setTimeout(checkForMatch, 500)
            this.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
        }
    } ```
````

Comment: One option would be to check the `src` via `this.getAttribute('src')` to see if it hasn't already been flipped before doing anything.

Comment: i legit did that ;-; @Joe

Comment: The `src` was the same as the array was repeated to create the pairs. 

`fruitVegArray = [...fruitVegArray, ...fruitVegArray]`

I actually solved the double-tap match issue by comparing the data-id numbers which were used to form the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you can try using another if statement like this(based on your `setAttribute`)

```js
      function tumblerLift() {
        let cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id')
        this.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        cardsChosen.push(fruitVegArray[cardId].name)
        cardsChosenId.push(cardId)
        if(this.src==fruitVegArray[cardId].img){return null} //image already chosen
        this.setAttribute('src', fruitVegArray[cardId].img)
        console.log(fruitVegArray[cardId])
        if (cardsChosen.length === 2) {
            setTimeout(checkForMatch, 500)
            this.style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [an answer by The Bomb Squad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990328), the `null` solution helped fix another bug of fruit appearing after they had been matched.

Here is the code I have now:

```
    // Tumbler lift
    function tumblerLift() {
        if (this.src.includes('images/blank.png')) {
            return null
        } // prevents fruit from reappearing, credit Y0urs Truly from Github for helping fix this bug
```

It's feeling a lot more together now; the actual game can be played here: https://dandavies23.github.io/smoothie-moves/

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share your results/success; it's always good to [solve your own problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)! Note that we require *all* answers on Stack Overflow to provide a complete and self-contained solution to the problem. I don't have enough expertise about the subject matter to know whether this actually provides the full solution. If it doesn't, can you please [edit] to expand it? Make sure that you've read our [answer].